# Загрузить страницу из куки

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, cookie, браузер

Есть две веб-страницы. Пользователь заходит на первую и получает куки-файлик с кодом второй. На первой странице есть ссылка на вторую. Я хочу чтобы при нажатии на эту ссылку переход произошел очень быстро.

Правильно ли будет никак не менять первую страницу и вставить скрипт проверки куки и загрузки на вторую? Покажите что это примерно должен быть за скрипт.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Как связаны куки и скорость загрузки страницы? Может, вы имеете в виду кеш?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko , видимо да... (Я еще не очень хорошо в джаваскрипте разбираюсь, думал через куки надо.) Какие бывают универсальные кэши (для всех видов подключений) и как ими пользоваться?

Comment: Извините, я не могу ответить на ваш вопрос, он не понятный. Попробуйте сначала погуглить термины - кеш, куки. И напишите что вам надо в итоге?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko , гуглил уже) Подскажите что-нибудь по-конкретнее. Есть сайт из нескольких страниц и каждая страница знает подмножество страниц сайта, которые скорее всего откроет пользователь, когда дочитает данную. Я хочу чтобы пока пользователь читал данную страницу к нему на компьютер подгружалось это подмножество.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API попробуйте изучить тему Service Worker и тему PWA - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps . Или хотя бы `fetch` - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: @Leonid , я правильно понял, что если пока открыта некоторая страница, дернуть fetch'ем другие, то при переходе на них по ссылке, они возьмутся из кэша и загрузятся быстро? Если да, то правда ли, что этот кэш внутри компьютера пользователя и страницы откроются даже если ему в момент нажатия на ссылку обрезать интернет?

Comment: Страницы скорее всего имеют множество объектов для загрузки: изображения, скрипты, таблицы стилей и т.д. В кэше (если он принудительно не отключен) будут храниться только сами html документы, скорее всего. Поэтому здесь хорошенько надо поработать над тем, чтобы загрузить дополнительные ресурсы тоже. А потом, вряд ли выделенная память на одну вкладку позволит держать в кэше все ресурсы. А вот Сервис Воркер позволит гораздо больше.

Comment: @Leonid , там написано, что сервис воркер имеет всякие ограничения (не везде поддерживается, например). А "хорошенько поработать" -- это распарсить страничку и рекурсивно подергать fetch'ем эти объекты?